# How can I rearrange sections in a UITableView using drag and drop?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm developing a Xamarin.iOS application that lets users create sections and add items to them. I want to incorporate a drag and drop function to allow users to reorder the sections they've created.

I'm using a "UITableView" to display sections, which represent a series of items. Here's an example:

```
Section 0: Kitchen

    Row 0: Refrigerator

    Row 1: Table

Section 1: Bedroom

    Row 0: Bed

    Row 1: Wardrobe
```

I've managed to rearrange the rows using the drag and drop feature by following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/introduction-to-ios11/drag-and-drop).

However, I'm struggling with rearranging the sections using drag and drop. Should I use a custom "UILongPressGestureRecognizer"? Are there any helpful tips or libraries that could assist me with this?

Thank you

Comment: According to [Adopting Drag and Drop in a Table View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/adopting_drag_and_drop_in_a_table_view), it supports rearranging rows not sections.